# Using a Java Method from another Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, include, project

Similar questions to this have been asked several times, but none of the answers fits my situation.

I have a Java project which I originally wrote to run on a PC. The classes containing the functional stuff are separate from those containing the GUI and PC specific bits and pieces. Now, I want to reuse those "generic" classes in an Android version.

I've created a new project in Eclipse. I've used the Build Path / Link Source item to point to the folder of my original project. Now links to the the .java files appear within my new project. I still can't invoke a method from the original project in my new one. I believe this option is only to allow the files to appear in the project and that it doesn't actually do anything functional.

Elsewhere, I learned of the ability to add the source in the Source path tab of the Build Path / Configure Build Path option. No joy with that either.

Another responded suggested adding the original project in the Projects tab of this dialog. This didn't help, either.

I've even tried multiple cantations of "import." Not even sure I should need to. No luck.

How can I resolve my "blah cannot be resolved to a type" warning in my Android project, when trying to call the method from my non-Android project, please?

Is there something missing from the raw Java which is required for an Android build?

Comment: You could export your classes as a library and then link the library to your project.

Comment: Why can't I just link the source? If I'm going to build the classes into a library, I may as well just copy the source for the classes into the new project. There's got to be a better way.

Comment: So, I've exported my class files as a JAR and then imported that as a library to the new project. I still can't make use of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a snaphot/util jar of the common project and include the jar in classpath of the dependent projects. This will fix your IDE problem.

During the deployment, make sure to include this new JAR in lib/classpath location of the deployable projects.

Comment: Sounds like finalising the other classes. Won't that exercise have to be carried out again if the classes are modified? That doesn't seem to be terribly "reusable".

Comment: @KDM Not really. There are some tools available to handle this during build time. Some of the tools are [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). They have eclipse plugins also available to ease management.

Comment: I'm only starting out in Java, but that strikes me as a really bizarre omission. It leaves me baffled, then, as to the purpose of the "Link Source" and "Required Projects" options in the Build Path configuration. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: @KDM  "Link Source" and "Required Projects" options in the Build Path configuration are also options and they work. Need to get more details around your specific scenario to comment on the issue. The option I proposed is more generic one.